# Selecting the rows of each cell within a range object (VBA)

Tags: vba, select, range

I am trying to copy a range of data from one worksheet to another. The range is defined by the value in the A column matching a set value. I have been able to add each of the cells with the specified value into a range object, but I now have to select all the data in the rows of the cells which are in my range object in order to copy them to another sheet. Any advice?

Also, I am very new to VBA so I am sure my code formatting is terrible, but I really just need a solution to this particular problem. Thanks for the help!

```
Dim allAsNum As Range
Dim currAsNum As Range
Dim asnum
Dim j

Sheets("Full Log").Select
asnum = "searchingvalue"
    For j = 2 To CInt(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Range(Sheets("Full Log").Cells.Address).Cells(j, 1).Value = asnum Then
        If allAsNum Is Nothing Then
            Set allAsNum = Range(Sheets("Full Log").Cells.Address).Cells(j, 1)
        Else
            Set allAsNum = Union(allAsNum, Range(Sheets("Full Log").Cells.Address).Cells(j, 1))
        End If
    End If
    Next j
    
    Set currAsNum = allAsNum.Rows 'This is the line that I can't figure out
    currAsNum.Select
```

Comment: `allAsNum.EntireRow.Copy YourTargetRange`

Comment: AdvancedFilter is a much more efficient way to copy data based on selection criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Craner is right. However, some remarks to your code

a) Being a beginner is no excuse for not indenting your code. Simply follow the rule to add 1 to the level of indentation at every `Sub`, `If`, `For` and `With`-statement (this list is not complete, but you get the idea). Subtract 1 at the matching `End`-statement. Use a `<TAB>` for every indent.

b) Do not use select. Obligatory link to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

c) You use the correct technique to get the last row. However, this returns already a `Long` value, no need to cast it using `CInt`. For debugging reason, it is better to write this into a variable before using it. You should, by the way, declare you variable `j` as `Long` (and maybe think about a better name).

d) Your technique to read a cell works, but is unnecessarily complicated. Simply use `Cells(j, 1)`

Code could look like this:

```
Const asnum = "searchingvalue"
Dim allAsNum As Range
Dim rowCount as long, curRow as long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Full Log")   
    rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For curRow = 2 To rowCount 
        If .Cells(curRow , 1).Value = asnum Then
            If allAsNum Is Nothing Then
                Set allAsNum = .Cells(curRow, 1)
            Else
                Set allAsNum = Union(allAsNum, .Cells(curRow, 1)) 
            End If
        End If
    Next curRow 
End With
' (The destination of the following copy needs to be adapted to your needs)
allAsNum.EntireRow.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Comment: One note, that I failed to state.  If using `EntireRow` your paste must be in Column `A`.  The row can change but the column must be the first column or you will get an error as you cannot paste an entire row into a partial row.